# Android JSON Custom ListView with Webview

Tags: android, json, listview, webview

I'm using this [tutorial](http://www.androidhive.info/2014/07/android-custom-listview-with-image-and-text-using-volley/) .I'm trying to get image from Json .Listview works Well , When i click Listview (example: second line) i want to see image2 in webview , but  i have problem possition.

```
private static final String TAG = Jsonlol.class.getSimpleName();
private String url;
private List<ListItem> listItem = new ArrayList<ListItem>();
private ListView listView;
private CustomListAdapter adapter;
private Dialog webViewDialog;
private WebView webView;
private Button btClose;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.json_main);

    url = getString(R.string.hellojson);

    listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listview);
    adapter = new CustomListAdapter(this, listItem);
    listView.setAdapter(adapter);   
    listView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                        int position, long id) {
                    if(position == 0)
                    {
                        webView.loadUrl(" Image 1 HERE  ");

                        webViewDialog = new Dialog(Jsonlol.this);  
                        webViewDialog.getWindow().requestFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
                        webViewDialog.setContentView(R.layout.wepbas);  
                        webView = (WebView) webViewDialog.findViewById(R.id.wb_webview); 
                        webViewDialog.show(); 


                    }
                    if(position == 1)
                    {
                        webView.loadUrl(" Image 2 HERE ");

                        webViewDialog = new Dialog(Jsonlol.this);  
                        webViewDialog.getWindow().requestFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
                        webViewDialog.setContentView(R.layout.wepbas);  
                        webView = (WebView) webViewDialog.findViewById(R.id.wb_webview); 
                        webViewDialog.show(); 


                    }
                    } });




    JsonArrayPostRequest itemReq = new JsonArrayPostRequest(url,
            new Response.Listener<JSONArray>() {

                public void onResponse(JSONArray response) {

                    for (int i = 0; i < response.length(); i++) {
                        try {


                            JSONObject obj = response.getJSONObject(i);
                            ListItem item = new ListItem();
                            item.setTitle(obj.getString("title"));
                            item.setThumbnailUrl(obj.getString("image"));
                            item.setrlevel(obj.getString("rlevel"));

                            listItem.add(item);

                        } catch (JSONException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }

                    }

                    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                }


            }, new Response.ErrorListener() {

                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                    VolleyLog.d(TAG, "Error: " + error.getMessage());

                }
            });

    AppController.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(itemReq);
}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
}
```

here Json

```
[{
    "id": "1",
    "title": "Test 1",
    "image": "http://api.androidhive.info/json/movies/1.jpg",
    "image2": "http://api.androidhive.info/json/movies/1.jpg",
    "rlevel": "Test 1"
},
{
    "id": "2",
    "title": "Test 2",
    "image": "http://api.androidhive.info/json/movies/2.jpg",
    "image2": "http://api.androidhive.info/json/movies/2.jpg",
    "rlevel": "Test 2"
}]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you are calling `webView` at wrong place,

```
if(position == 0)
                {
                    webViewDialog = new Dialog(Jsonlol.this);  
                    webViewDialog.getWindow().requestFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
                    webViewDialog.setContentView(R.layout.wepbas);  
                    webView = (WebView) webViewDialog.findViewById(R.id.wb_webview); 
                    webView.loadUrl(listItem.get(0).getThumbnailUrl());
                    webViewDialog.show(); 
                }
                if(position == 1)
                {
                    webViewDialog = new Dialog(Jsonlol.this);  
                    webViewDialog.getWindow().requestFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
                    webViewDialog.setContentView(R.layout.wepbas);  
                    webView = (WebView) webViewDialog.findViewById(R.id.wb_webview); 
                    webView.loadUrl(listItem.get(1).getThumbnailUrl());
                    webViewDialog.show(); 
                }
```

But if your aim is only showing image when users clicked to your list item, you can try to show your image to an `ImageView` with [`picasso`](http://square.github.io/picasso/) , [`ion`](https://github.com/koush/ion) and this kind of libraries.

Comment: Works perfectly . Thank you very much, sir.